# Bootstrap datepicker not popping out in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I saw lot of post regarding this but not able to solve.

In my view the bootstrap datepicker is popping out successfully for the input tag
eg:

```html
<input class="span2 datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
```

When i run the page iam able to change the date through datepicker.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
```

but the same is not working with below code

```html
<div class="control-group">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.dob, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
<div class="controls">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dob, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "datepicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dob, "", new { @class = "field-validation-error text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sorted out.

```html
<div class="control-group">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.dob, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
<div class="controls">
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dob, new {@class = "datepicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dob, "", new { @class = "field-validation-error text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

I removed `new { htmlAttributes =`  from the `Editorfor`

and its working fine :)

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.dob, new {@class = "datepicker" } }) `does not add a `class` attribute (check the html your generating) so unless you have a custom `EditorTemplate` for `DateTime` this means you rendering the HMTL5 datepicker, not a Bootstrap datepicker